# Data exchange exchange between Google Apps & another site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, stackmob

G'day folks

In short I'm wanting to know whether it is possible for Google Apps to exchange data with another site using the other site's REST APIs?

In my specific case I have a mobile backend running on StackMob & am exploring Google Apps as a possible solution for data management. For that to work it's vital that I can communicate between Google Apps & StackMob using StackMob's API.

Cheers & TIA,
Pedro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Google Apps Script's UrlFetch Service to communicate between Google Apps and rest API of StackMob.
Here is the reference URL which will help you
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch

Usage example of URLFetch with Twitter API
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial

Comment: Thanks Waqar, looks like just what I needed :)